# Apache Cassandra and Spring - org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type

Tags: spring-data-jpa, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I am getting the ConverterNotFoundException when trying to save the data in Apache Cassandra using the Spring/Spring Boot application. The following is the complete exception stack trace.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.xxxxx.scenario.model.entity.EventMetadata] to type [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.data.UdtValue]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:322) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:195) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:175) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ConvertingPropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(ConvertingPropertyAccessor.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ConvertingPropertyAccessor.getProperty(ConvertingPropertyAccessor.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.getWriteValue(MappingCassandraConverter.java:909) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.4.6.jar!/:3.4.6]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.writeInternal(MappingCassandraConverter.java:654) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.4.6.jar!/:3.4.6]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.write(MappingCassandraConverter.java:620) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.4.6.jar!/:3.4.6]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.StatementFactory.insert(StatementFactory.java:307) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.4.6.jar!/:3.4.6]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.doInsert(CassandraTemplate.java:674) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.4.6.jar!/:3.4.6]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:664) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.4.6.jar!/:3.4.6]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.SimpleCassandraRepository.save(SimpleCassandraRepository.java:96) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.4.6.jar!/:3.4.6]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor245.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at datadog.trace.instrumentation.springdata.RepositoryInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryInterceptor.java:41) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy283.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.xxxxxxx.scenario.service.ScenarioResultServiceImpl.saveProductPrice(ScenarioResultServiceImpl.java:94) ~[lib-product-price-scenario-1.1.125.jar!/:na]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

I have the cassandra types defined as follows for the field but it's failing to save it in the cassandra tables.

```
    @CassandraType(
            type = CassandraType.Name.UDT,
            userTypeName = "scenario_calculated_values"
    )
    @Column("calculated_values")
    private ScenarioCalculatedValues calculatedValues;
```

The following are the versions used in the application.
spring-core-5.3.22.jar!
spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar!
spring-data-cassandra-3.4.6.jar!
DataStax Java Driver 4.14.1!

Here is the ScenarioCalcuatedValues class for reference:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.UserDefinedType;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@UserDefinedType("scenario_calculated_values")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class ScenarioCalculatedValues {
    @Column("ltv")
    private BigDecimal ltv;
    @Column("combined_ltv")
    private BigDecimal combinedLtv;
    @Column("high_combined_ltv")
    private BigDecimal highCombinedLtv;
}
```

Here is the EventMetaData class for reference:

```
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.UserDefinedType;

import com.google.common.collect.Sets;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@UserDefinedType("metadata_response")
public class EventMetadata {
    @Column("event_source")
    private String eventSource;

    @Column("reasons")
    private Set<Reason> reasons = Sets.newHashSet();
}
```

Comment: The stack trace references EventMetadata but that is not included in your code provided - what is the definition of it?

Comment: Please check the above updated EventMetadata class.

Comment: I do not see where `EventMetadata` is used in your code, `ScenarioCalculatedValues` is useless in that context